# trying to change what image is displayed on pages in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a magento site I'm working on and I'm having some trouble finding where to change what image is displayed on each of my category pages.

http://nexlevelhost.com/~ultimate/index.php/

On the product menu on the home page, you see a list of everything from Air Intakes to Transmission. If you go to those categories, you'll see that there is an image on the top of the page with "Ultimate performance & design" and then "Brakes". This is all good and fine for the "brakes" category, but the same image displays on all the categories. I have different images with their respective names on them for each category. I can't seem to find where to make each of those pages display their own image, instead of them all displaying the same thing. The actual path to that image is: http://nexlevelhost.com/~ultimate/skin/frontend/default/em0060/images/media/862x328.jpg

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: How is that image displayed? Did you add it under `Magento Admin->Catalog->Manage Categories->Display Settings` as a static block? or did you add it to the category as `->General Settings->Image`?

Comment: I'm using a magento theme. It looks like it is set up as a static block called "Category Top Banner". The code inside the block looks like this:

<div class="category-banner"><a title="category-banner" href="#"> <img class="image-banner" src="{{skin url='images/media/862x328.jpg'}}" alt="category-banner" /> </a></div>

Comment: So, really, I guess what I need to do is edit them page by page, but I don't know where to go to make those changes for each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a magento theme, you are stuck with what is being used, and it can be hard to determine what is displaying from where.

Your first place to look is the Magento Admin->Catalog->Manage Categories->Thumbnail Image and see if it is set to the large image. I have done that in the past to place an image on a category. Barred that, turn on template path hints and see if you can determine the phtml file that displays the image (it will have the name in the red box).

I suggest installing the Easy Template Path Hints free plugin
[LINK HERE](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html)

Its a real quick way to turn the template path hints on and off instead of digging through admin every time you want to see them. It will lead you to the place the images are set. I don't write this plugin, but i use it on our dev and prod site to help find problems that crop up from time to time when other people edit the site and we end up with html errors.

Comment: No problem. That easy template path thing is a lifesaver, especially when the boss wants something thrown up on a screen real quick and you have no idea what template file is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys I figured it out. I removed the category-banner from all the categories and then just added the image at Magento Admin->Catalog->Manage Categories->Display Settings and choose image.

Comment: That's the direction I was headed in, since one would have to assign the same image to all the categories, or assign a static block to show with the products, and have them all use the same block.